# Derivation of the adjoint of Dirac equation

Tags: field-theory, conventions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

> My **goal** is to deduce the adjoint of Dirac equation:
>   $$
> \overline \psi (i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu+m)=0 \tag{1}
> $$

My **process**: I started with Dirac equation $(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu-m)\psi=0$. Taking the Hermitian adjoint of Dirac equation, I got

$$
\psi^\dagger(-i(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger\partial_\mu-m)=0 \tag{2}
$$
As we all know, the hermitian adjoint of $\gamma^\mu$ is that $(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger=\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$. Substituating $(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger=\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$ into equation (2), I got
$$
\psi^\dagger(-i\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0\partial_\mu-m)=0  \\
(\psi^\dagger\gamma^0)(-i\gamma^\mu\gamma^0\partial_\mu-m)=0 \tag{3}
$$

By $\overline \psi= \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$, we have 
$$
\overline \psi (i\gamma^\mu\gamma^0 \partial_\mu+m)=0 \tag{4}
$$

We can see that equation (4) is different with equation (1). (we all know that equation (1) is the right form) I have tried multiplying from the right of eq. (4) by $\gamma^0$(using $(\gamma^0)^2=1$), the adjoint equation

$$
\overline \psi (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m\gamma^0)=0 \tag{5}
$$

Equation (5) is still different with equation (1).

I am frustrated. I hope that someone could help me to build the process from eq.(5) to eq.(1).

Comment: In step 1 and 3a you should still have a minus sign in front of m unless it and step 3 are typos.

Comment: Your actual error is in step 3b, you factor a $\gamma^0$ out but this requires that both terms inside the parenthesis have a $\gamma^0$ to factor, you can fix this by changing $m$ to $\gamma^0 m \gamma^0$

Comment: @Triatticus Oh, now I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with
$$
i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi-m\psi=0.
$$
Take its h.c.:
$$
-i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0\partial_\mu-\psi^\dagger m=0.
$$
Multiply by $\gamma^0$ from the right, and use $\bar{\psi}=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0$,
$$
i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+\bar{\psi}m=0.
$$

The mistake is in your step (3) as pointed out by @Triatticus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.....I made a mistake in my derivation

Answer (score 1):

When you pull $\gamma^0$ to the left, you have forgotten the mass term which  should have been multiplied before by $1=(\gamma^0)^2$ so you'd get
$-\psi^{\dagger}(i\partial_{\mu} (\gamma^0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^0)+(\gamma^0)^2m)=0$

Comment: Then, you multiply by $\gamma^0$ from the right.